# MongoDB: Pushing a new object to array and returning the same

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, nosql

My MongoDB document structure for a `Category` is like this

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5e487ce64787a51f073d0915"),
  "active" : true,
  "name" : "Luggage",
  "productList" : [ 
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5e487ce64787a51f073d0adf"),
      "name" : "Duffle Bag"
    }, 
    {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5e487ce64787a51f073d0wt4"),
      "name" : "Trolley Bag"
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add a new object to `productList` array and return the same in a single query?

Looking into MongoDB method `updateOne`, it returns update operation results so it is not useful. Another option I see is to use `findAndModify`, return the `Category` document and then iterate through all the products. Match by `name` and return. But this is not very efficient. I am looking for a solution on MongoDB level and not code level. Is there anything in MongoDB I can leverage?

Comment: what is your input request ? If you've to return the same object then why not to return input request itself if DB update is successful ? Do you need the auto-generated `ObjectId()` as well ? - then you've to get the doc & iterate over it to get respective object.

Comment: Well, if you are looking for a temporary field(*Ie. not updated in db but is in the output result*). You could make use of either `$set` or `$addFields`(*depending on the version you are using*) in your agergation pipeline.

Comment: For the `findAndModify` method there is an option called as `fields`. This option when used with the `new: true` option, returns only the _projected_ (specific) fields from the returned modified document. You can specify only to return the `productList` field.

Comment: MongoDB allows to project only a specific array element from the `findAndModify` returned document, but it doesn't allow with the `new:true` option. That means you cannot return the newly inserted array element.